# Formula for inverse weighted average (smaller value gets higher weight)

Tags: python, weighted-mean

In Python, I have some `'VALUE'` with a metric for `'WEIGHT'` in a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas

frame = pandas.DataFrame(
    {
        'VALUE': [1,2,3,4,5]
        , 'WEIGHT': [23, 21, 10, 3, 0]
    }
)

#       VALUE  WEIGHT
#    0      1      23
#    1      2      21
#    2      3      10
#    3      4       3
#    4      5       0
```

I'd like to make a weighted average of `'VALUE'`, but the logic should give more weight to smaller values of `'WEIGHT'`.  What's a generally accepted formula for accomplishing this?  Thanks!

Comment: Two possibilities are ` 1 - (frame.WEIGHT / frame.WEIGHT.sum())` and `(frame.WEIGHT.sum() / (frame.WEIGHT + 1))`.

Comment: "Generally accepted" has little meaning, because there are infinitely many possible formulas and the one you choose ought to be appropriate for your analytical objectives.  Could you explain *why* you want to weight the data and what the weighting needs to accomplish?

Comment: @whuber It's from a K-Nearest-Neighbor analysis.  I've identified the closest neighbors' values to a point with their respective distances.  Now I'd like to assign those same values to my point weighted inversely by their distance.

Comment: Do you mean [IDW interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting)?

Comment: @whuber that looks promising...would you know a good method to utilize that in Python?  Would you recommend the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104781/inverse-distance-weighted-idw-interpolation-with-python

Comment: I haven't tried out the code, but the accepted answer there takes the right approach and it looks pretty well crafted.